# What will be the algorithm to solve the given series?

Tags: java, algorithm

What will be the algorithm for calculating the given series?

[Series to be calculated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEPqN.png)

Here's what I coded till now:

```
public static double sumOfSeries(double x, int numTerms) { // -1 <= x <= 1
        double sum = x;
        for(int i = 1; i <= numTerms; i++) {

        }       
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: What did you try to come up with? Since this looks like an exercise whose purpose probably is either to test you or to teach you something it is _you_ who should do the first attempt.

Comment: And what are you planning to do with `i`? Did you try to analyze the series and create a formula/step definition based on `i`?

Comment: This question does not show enough effort for Stack Overflow. But here's a hint: think of it as two intertwined series. Solve for the two separate series first. After that, see if you can intertwine them; your teacher probably wants the answer in a single `for` loop.

Comment: Using `i` as the loop counter only is one way but you can do more (e.g. you could do something like `pow(x, i * 2 - 1)` etc.). Even if not, you need to decompose the series and find a pattern that can be implemented in the loop body which is the actual task. And that's what I guess _you_ are supposed to try at least - and you should definitly show what you've tried here so that we can make suggestions.

Comment: I'm not able to come up with a stable algorithm to solve the problem. So I haven't written any code yet. @Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to separate the coefficients from polynomials and calculate those in separate methods. Example:

```
        public class NewClass {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
             int greatestExponent = 9;
             double x = 0.5;
             System.out.println(calculate(x,greatestExponent));
        }
        public static double getCoefficient(int n){
            double coff = 1;
            for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
                if(i%2==0){
                    coff = coff/i;       //if even put it in the denominator
                }
                else{
                    coff = coff*i;       // else numerator 
                }
            }
            return coff/n;          // at the end divide with the exponent (ex. x^9 /9)
        }
        public static double calculate(double x, int expo){
            double result = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i<= expo; i+=2){
                result +=  (getCoefficient(i)*Math.pow(x, i)); //for each odd exponent calculate the cofficient and x^i
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Necessary to find all regularity in proposed equation.

x -> x^3 -> x^5 -> x^7 ->

Then you make separate variable N1=x before loop and N1 *= x*2 at the end of each iteration

1 -> 1 -> 1x3 -> 1x3x5 -> 1x3x5x7 ->

Separate variable N2=1 before lopp and N2 *= (i*2-1) at the end of each iteration

etc, etc

finaly you will combine all this parts together at start of each iteration, like sum += N1*N2*N3/(N4*N5)